# How to login a user during a unit test in Django REST Framework?

Tags: django, unit-testing, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

This is my DRF view:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def check_user(request):
    user = request.user
    # use user object here
    return JSONResponse({})
```

And this is my unit test for said view:

```
class CheckUserViewTest(TestCase):

    def test_check_user(self):
        user = User.objects.create_user('username', 'Pas$w0rd')
        self.client.login(username='username', password='Pas$w0rd')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('check_user'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, httplib.OK)
```

But I always get a `401` `UNAUTHORIZED` response from my view. I have logged in the user in my test. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18):

Since you are using Django REST Framework you have to also use DRF's test client called `APIClient` instead of Django's test client. This happens automagically if you inherit from DRF's `APITestCase` instead of Django's `TestCase`.

Complete example:

```
class CheckUserViewTest(APITestCase):

    def test_check_user(self):
        user = User.objects.create_user('username', 'Pas$w0rd')
        self.assertTrue(self.client.login(username='username', password='Pas$w0rd'))
        response = self.client.get(reverse('check_user'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, httplib.OK)
```

An alternative is to use `force_authenticate`:

```
class CheckUserViewTest(APITestCase):

    def test_check_user(self):
        user = User.objects.create_user('username', 'Pas$w0rd')
        self.client.force_authenticate(user)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('check_user'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, httplib.OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are using `djangorestframework` you must have to use `APITestCase` here.

An complete `example` is just below

```
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password


class TestLogin(APITestCase):
    '''
    This will handle login testcases
    '''

    def setUp(self):
        self.url = reverse('check_user')
    

    def test_login(self):
        '''
        This will test successfull login
        '''
        data = {
            "full_name" : "full name",
            'email' : "email@gmail.com",
            'password' : "password"
            }

        User.objects.create(
            full_name = data.get('full_name'),
            email = data.get('email'),
            password = make_password(data.get('password'))
            )
        
        response = self.client.get(self.url, data=data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code,status.HTTP_200_OK)
```