# How to fix this error failed to import test module while testing?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Here I'm writing some TestCase for some queryset to view in api and getting error not a valid function or pattern name. I didn't get any idea what missing here! Is there any solution for this?

views.py

```
class  StudentView(generics.ListAPIView):
queryset = StudentDetails.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM 
           collegedetails.college_studentdetails LIMIT 3;')
serializer_class = StudentDetailsSerializers
```

test_views.py

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from rest_framework import status

STUDENT_URL = reverse('student/')
class StudentsDetailsTest(APITestCase):
def test_details(self):
    response = self.client.get(STUDENT_URL, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

college/urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[

        path('student/',views.StudentView.as_view(), name='student'),
]
```

traceback error

```
Found 1 test(s).
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
E
======================================================================
ERROR: college.tests (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: college.tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\\collegedjango\MYSITE\college\tests.py", line 33, in 
<module>
    STUDENT_URL = reverse('student')
  File "C:\Users\\collegedjango\venv\lib\site- 
packages\rest_framework\reverse.py", line 47, in reverse
    url = _reverse(viewname, args, kwargs, request, format, **extra)
  File "C:\Users\\collegedjango\venv\lib\site- 
packages\rest_framework\reverse.py", line 60, in _reverse
    url = django_reverse(viewname, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, **extra)
  File "C:\Users\\collegedjango\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\urls\base.py", line 86, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\\collegedjango\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 729, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'student' not found. 
 'student' is not a valid view function or pattern name.


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: Did you define an `app_name` in your `urls.py` or a `namespace` when you use `include(...)`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ya define an app_name='student_api'  in college/urls.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used an `app_name = 'student_api'`, this means that you should *prefix* the name of the view with that `app_name`, so:

```
STUDENT_URL = reverse('student_api:student')
```

You should furthermore remove the slash at the end: the `reverse` uses the *name* of the view (prefixed with the `app_name` or `namespace` if you defined one), not the path pattern.

Comment: getting error AssertionError: 403 != 200 by means should i create setup user login?

Comment: @user17821553: if your view requres that a user logs in, you should indeed use an authentication token, or any other means how you authorize a request.

Comment: how to setup in testcase to authentication to login?

Comment: @user17821553: you can create a user and log in the client before making the `.get` request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47184778/67579